# IndexError: list index out of range в чем ошибка?

Tags: python

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в морфологическом словаре odict в формате csv найти начальную форму для каждого слова в предложении. Эта начальная форма является первым элементом каждой строки списка, после которой идут словоформы.

Вот мой код:

```
input_data = open("input.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
text = input_data.read()
cleartext = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','', text)
cleartext_low = str(''.join(cleartext)).lower()
tokens = word_tokenize(cleartext_low)


data = csv.reader(open('odict.csv', 'r'))
reader = list(data)


res = []
i = 0
while i <= len(tokens):
    for i in range(len(tokens)):
        for row in reader:
            if tokens[i] in row:
                res.append(row[0])
                i += 1
print(res)
```

В моем коде вылетает

> *IndexError: list index out of range* на *if tokens[i] in row:*.

Что можно сделать с кодом, чтобы исправить ошибку?

Comment: "Как записать в новый список первый элемент строки списка, если в нем есть нужный элемент из другого списка?" - можно как-то переделать понятнее вопрос,что-то слишком сложно

Comment: простите, изменила)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for token in tokens:
    for row in reader:
        if token in row:
            res.append(row[0])
```